# Laravel dropdown list recovers old value and data stored in database

Tags: php, laravel, dropdown, laravel-blade

it’s simple I have a single form for adding a student and editing a student and I want to recover the old values when a user misses on a field and when I edit a student recover in the Select what was stored in the database(regions of the student). it’s a school project and I’ve been stuck on it for too long.

Class Demande and Student are in relation ship.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="region">Region&nbsp;<span class="important">(in France) </span>:</label>
      <select name="regionStudent" class="form-control @error('regionStudent') is-invalid @enderror" id="region">
        @foreach ($demande->student->getRegionStudentOptions() as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}"
          {{ old('regionStudent') == $key ?? $demande->student->regionStudent  == $value ? 'selected' : ''}}>
          {{ $value }}
        </option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      @error('regionStudent')
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{$errors->first('regionStudent')}}
      </div>
      @enderror
    </div>
```

my array :

```
public function getRegionStudentAttribute($attributes)
    {
        return $this->getRegionStudentOptions()[$attributes];
    }
public function getRegionStudentOptions()
{
    return [
        '' => 'Selectionner votre région',
        '1' => 'Alsace',
        '2' => 'Aquitaine',
        '3' => 'Auvergne',
        '4' => 'Basse Normandie',
        '5' => 'Bourgogne',
        '6' => 'Bretagne',
        '7' => 'Centre',
        '8' => 'Champagne-Ardenne',
        '9' => 'Corse',
        '10' => 'Franche-Comté'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by checking the value aswell. I think you should only check by the key... and I think the correct way to do this is `{{ old('regionStudent') == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}`

Comment: you probably want `$demande->student->regionStudent == $key` instead of comparing against the value

Comment: – Daniel R i can't juste do old i need to recover information stored in database.

Comment: – lagbox yeah you are right, but when i edit a post it's doesn't recovers data from database, it just reset like in the add form. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQxf9.png